# Final Delta flights out of Athens Airport ATH (Airfrance, Alitalia, KLM)

Tags: air-travel, airlines, ath

I'm booking a trip to Athens, Greece from JFK. I planned on returning to the US on March 18th, but I called Delta, who told me that the last day that their partners (Airfrance, Alitalia, and KLM) will be flying out of Athens is March 17th. So, I am booked for March 17th, the last flight from Athens according to them.

Does anyone know why Delta is stopping their flights after the 17th? They didn't say why, but I could only think of corona virus-related precautions or issues with Turkey.

Is this any reason for concern? Could I end up getting stranded in Greece? If it matters, my flight has a short layover at CDG.

Any insight regarding this specific situation or situations similar to it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: They still show as bookable on delta.com for March 18th.

Comment: The only direct ATH-CDG flights by Delta partners are operated by AF, and they are still scheduled for every single day of March and April. If you consider all ATH-JFK flights on Skyteam, there are plenty of options every day via CDG, AMS, FCO, or SVO. Either you had a misunderstanding, or there was a glitch in their booking system, there's definitely no disruption planned on those flights (yet, at least).

Comment: @MichaelHampton They show as bookable, yes, however, when I called them, they showed up as cancelled on their end. The attendant even had to go to the support desk.

Comment: @jcaron I'll refer you to my comment above, which applies for both AMS and FCO. It's funny because I looked them up now and ATH-CDG seems bookable from google flights. Yet, when I search ATH-JFK, I see nothing even bookable from their partners.

Comment: You can always book a non direct flight to JFK.